# Dimension of projective lines

Tags: geometry

In an exercise, I have a vector space V of dimension 4 and a projective space P(V) of dimension 3.
Now I wonder what dimension projective lines have. Is it possible that the dimension of the projective lines always has dimension 1? Or does it depend on the dimension of the projective space P(V)?

In the lecture, we defined the dimension of projective lines with the dimension of 1.
I am not sure if this is true for any projective space, regardless of the dimension of the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *projective line* in $\mathbf{P}(V)$ is the image of a two-dimensional vector subspace of $V$, regardless of the dimension of $V$.